# Mac OS X users in an Active Directory based network

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

In your corporate network, how do you handle Mac OS X users on your Active Directory based network? What are some specific things you do to cater to the Mac OS users?

We are specifically having issues with the following:

- Password expirations (specifically that there is no notification given to the user while they are logged in).
- Finder not consistent about using kerberos. Browse to a windows server in "All..." and open a SMB share, you'll have to authenticate. However when you use Finder's "Go to Folder..." action or access via `smbclient -k` the system will properly use kerberos. Is this a bug? Is there any work around? Do you just mount the needed drives at logon? If so, how do you manage these login scripts?
- VMs. Nearly everyone uses either Parallels Desktop or VMWare Fusion. Do you join these VMs to the domain as well? Do you do anything else special with VMs?
- File share compatibility. If we let the Mac users use an SMB share on a Windows server, the Macs have to leave `.DS_Store` everywhere for compatibility. Letting the Windows users use SMB on a Mac server is my best option, as the Mac users can use AFP (enabling the use of resource forks, instead of leaving .DS_Store everywhere). Additionally this will allow Mac OS users to use spotlight on the server mounts.
- The directory application shows a number of system accounts, cluttering it up. Do your users even bother using this application? If so have you found a way to hide them?

Comment: There have been a couple questions about .DS_Store files that can help: http://serverfault.com/search?q=.DS_Store

Answer (score 6):

I have a few Xserves running as file servers in an Active Directory environment.  The golden triangle approach has worked great for me:  http://www.bombich.com/mactips/activedir.html.  I set mine up following those directions exactly, and here's my experiences:

1. I do get a password expiration notification when I log in as an AD user.  I would say pay special attention to the kerberos part of the Golden Triangle approach.  The key most people miss is `sudo dsconfigad -enableSSO`.
2. I think the kerberos part above would also fix this.  Works both ways for me.
3. What I've done a few times is use Boot Camp to create a physical Windows environment, join that to AD, then let them run it via VMware Fusion from OS X if they wish.
4. I have a Windows server, and feel your .DS_Store pain.  However, this command helps:  `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true`
5. At the top window of Directory.app, you can select "People" to filter out the junk.

Active Directory provides the username and password, as well as some group memberships and user policies.  AD only targets Windows users.  I don't have admin rights on Active Directory.  I have to get permission to join my Xserves to the domain.  I have no ability to modify the AD schema at all.  If I wanted to extend certain OS X specific policies to my Mac users, I can do so via my Open Directory master.  The Bombich document explains how.

Hope that helps some!

Comment: #1 - My kerberos is fully functioning, and I do get a reset on log in as well. I'm concerned about users who don't log out often never receiving notice.

#2- Again kerberos is operating fine, that's how Finder's "Go To Folder..." works. Additionally I've verified using that utility in Keychain.

#3- Not a bad idea.

#4- Yes I know about that one, it does not help as it disables functionality (ie: labels)

#5- This doesn't filter system use accounts.

So basically you join your Macs to Open Directory, Active Directory or both? I assume this is via Directory Utility?

Comment: Also dsconfigad -enableSSO is only for OS X Server according to it's man page.

Comment: No, dsconfigad -enableSSO is for clients too.  It's just the command line tool for configuring the AD plugin which exists in both OS X Server and Client.  Not much difference between the two anyway.

Sounds like you're not using OD yet.  I would give it a shot.  Things work better in AD when OD is on.  Yes, join the Mac clients to both AD & OD as the Bombich white paper outlines.  It's step by step, you can't go wrong with it.

Only other solution for Windows File Server that I know of is http://www.grouplogic.com/products/extremeZ-IP/.

Answer (score 0):

Windows VM's get joined to the domain, and are treated (almost) like any other PC on the network. (So it get's patched, get AV installed, etc.) We don't let people bring in any old PC, why should a VM be any different? (We might make an exception for a development-type VM that was fake-network only or something...)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of requirements check out LikeWise.

Tom